# Improve BNF for mathematic expressions

Tags: parsing, calculator, bnf

A good exercise while learning programming, is to write a calculator. To do this, I created some kind of [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) in [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) and want to ask for your help to improve it. With this minilanguage you should be able to `add`, `multiply` and `assign` values and expressions to names (a.k.a. create variables and functions).

Hava a look at the BNF first:

```
<Program>     ::= <Line>(<NewLine><Line>)*
<Line>        ::= {"("}<Expression>{")"}|<Assignment>
<Assignment>  ::= <Identifier>"="<Expression>
<Identifier>  ::= <Name>{"("<Name>(","<Name>)*")"}
<Expression>  ::= <Summand>(("+"|"-")<Summand>)*
<Summand>     ::= <Factor>(("*"|"/")<Factor>)*
<Factor>      ::= <Number>|<Call>
<Call>        ::= <Name> {"("<Expression>(","<Expression>)*")"}
<Name>        ::= <Letter>(<Letter>|<Digit>)*
<Number>      ::= {"+"|"-"}(<Digit>|<DigitNoZero><Digit>+)
<Digit>       ::= "0"|<DigitNoZero>
<DigitNoZero> ::= "1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"7"|"8"|"9"
<Letter>      ::= [a-zA-Z]
<NewLine>     ::= "\n"|"\r"|"\r\n"
```

As you can see, this BNF treats no Whitespace beside `NewLine`. Before the parsing begins I plan to remove all whitespace (beside `NewLine` of course) from the string to parse. It is not nessesary for the parser anyway.

There are 4 things, that might lead to **problems** when using this language as defined right now and I hope you can help me figure out appropriate solutions:

1. I tried to follow the top-down approach, while generating this gramar, but there is a circle between `<Expression>`, `<Summand>`, `<Factor>` and `<Call>`.
2. The gramar treats variables and functions exactly the same way. Most programming languages make a difference. **Is it nessesary to differentiate here?**
3. There are maybe some things that I don't know about programming, BNF, whatever, that will kill me later, while trying to implement the BNF. But you might be able to spot that before I start.
4. There might be simple and stupid mistakes that I could not find myself. Sorry in that case. I hope there are none of these mistakes anymore.

Using hand and brain I could successfully parse the following test cases:

```
"3"
"-3"
"3-3"
"a=3"
"a=3+b"
"a=3+b\nc=a+3"
"a(b,c)=b*c\ra(1+2,2*3)"
```

Please help to improve the BNF, that it can be used to successfully write a calculator.

**edit:**
This BNF is really not finished. It does not treat the cases "2+-3" (should fail, but doesn't) and "2+(-3)" (should not fail, but does) correctly.

Comment: "there is a circle between <Expression>, <Summand>, <Factor> and <Call>." Yes, there is. Why is this an issue for you?

Comment: I dont think you can describe an unambiguous language in BNF except for the smallest cases. YACC (and friends) solves these issues, so you dont have to.

Comment: @Paul I don't know. That is what I want to find out.

Comment: @leppie I never used yacc, but I thought it generates a parser based on your BNF. So of course you have to write BNF or something very similar. Or do you mean, I should not try to parse the BNF? That I will not try. Based on the BNF I can easily write a simple (but maybe not so efficient) program, that can read this language.

Comment: @erikb: YACC will shout at you, if your language is ambiguous. BNF will not. :)  I agree, they are similar in syntax.

Comment: @leppie so this is ambigious? Why? Because of the loop?

Comment: I don't fully understand your concerns. The BNF looks OK to me. Your grammar is inherently recursive because function parameters can be expressions, but that's not necessarily a problem.  It would help if you explained what issues you are concerned about in  more detail

Comment: @Paul did you ever make a plan first, then started to program and when nearly finished found out that this approach can not work? I just want to avoid this and thus hope somebody looks over my plan, before I execute on it. For the recursiveness I found a simple answer myself, thanks to thinking about how to respond to you. Don't know how to point out more. Is it normal, that the BNF does not differentiate between Variables and Functions? Is it normal, that the BNF is recursive?

Comment: I often find the only way to find out if an approach doesn't work is to try it. I'd fire up the language of your choice and give it a go. It's normal that the grammar doesn't distringuish between variables and functions - from the point of view of htet expression, they both just return values. And it's very normal for the BNF to be recursive, since your language is...

Comment: Well maybe I try too hard to find errors, where actually no errors are. I just can not believe so easily that I make no mistakes on my first try. Of course we used BNF for some small exercises in school, but never to define a real, usable, language. I have to assume my classes where really good.

Comment: I'm not sure why you feel 2+-3 should fail. It's unambigous. Also,  your grammar doesn't specify factors can be bracketed expressions, but that's not necessarily an error. So the grammar can't really be reviewed without understanding the language you had in mind that it is intended to be a grammar for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The gramar treats variables and functions exactly the same way. Most programming languages make a difference. Is it nessesary to differentiate here?

Being able to treat *the result of a function invocation* exactly the same as *a local variable or a constant expression* is precisely the point of defining (mathematical) functions in the first place. I can't imagine the use of a grammar that allowed functions but didn't treat

```
1 + 1
```

exactly the same as

```
1 + a
```

or

```
1 + sin(x)
```