# Representing ad-hoc operator precedence in Scala Parser

Tags: scala, parsing, context-free-grammar

So I'm trying to write a parser specifically for the arithmetic fragment of a programming language I'm playing with, using scala RegexParsers.
As it stands, my top-level expression parser is of the form:

```
parser: Parser[Exp] = binAppExp | otherKindsOfParserLike | lval | int
```

It accepts lvals (things like `"a.b, a.b[c.d], a[b], {record=expression, like=this}"` just fine. Now, I'd like to enable expressions like `"1 + b / c = d"`, but potentially with (source language, not Scala) compile-time user-defined operators.

My initial thought was, if I encode the operations recursively and numerically by precedence, then I could add higher precedences ad-hoc, and each level of precedence could parse consuming lower-precedence sub-terms on the right-side of the operation expression. So, I'm trying to build a toy of that idea with just some fairly common operators.
So I'd expect `"1 * 2+1"` to parse into something like `Call(*, Seq(1, Call(+ Seq(2,1))))`, where `case class Call(functionName: String, args: Seq[Exp]) extends Exp`.

Instead though, it parses as `IntExp(1)`.

Is there a reason that this can't work (is it left-recursive in a way I'm missing? If so, I'm sure there's something else wrong, or it'd never terminate, right?), or is it just plain wrong for some other reason?

```
  def binAppExp: Parser[Exp] = {
    //assume a registry of operations
    val ops = Map(
      (7, Set("*", "/")),
      (6, Set("-", "+")),
      (4, Set("=", "!=", ">", "<", ">=", "<=")),
      (3, Set("&")),
      (2, Set("|"))
    )

    //relevant ops for a level of precedence
    def opsWithPrecedence(n: Int): Set[String] = ops.getOrElse(n, Set.empty)

    //parse an op with some level of precedence
    def opWithPrecedence(n: Int): Parser[String] = ".+".r ^? (
      { case s if opsWithPrecedence(n).contains(s) => s },
      { case s => s"SYMBOL NOT FOUND: $s" }
      )

    //assuming the parse happens, encode it as an AST representation
    def folder(h: Exp, t: LangParser.~[String, Exp]): CallExp =
      CallExp(t._1, Seq(h, t._2))

    val maxPrecedence: Int = ops.maxBy(_._1)._1

    def term: (Int => Parser[Exp]) = {
      case 0 => lval | int | notApp | "(" ~> term(maxPrecedence) <~ ")"
      case n =>
        val lowerTerm = term(n - 1)
        lowerTerm ~ rep(opWithPrecedence(n) ~ lowerTerm) ^^ {
          case h ~ ts => ts.foldLeft(h)(folder)
        }
    }

    term(maxPrecedence)
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like these are regexes. It may be a context free thing (like BNF), but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. I'm using the scala parser combinators (and scala regex parsers are a subset of that), I just wanted to give context on the libraries I'm using.

Comment: OK, I see you have the one regex: `.+`, but I don't know any Scala to tell how it fits in. I do know that you should be able to parse stuff like that with a CFG parser (which I assume that it is).

Comment: Yeah, it's too late to edit the title/tags, this is the portion of the parser which involves very little in the way of regexes. But there's nothing inherently impossible about dynamically recurring down the precedence of the operators?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3811325/6083675) is an example of a similar parser written in BNF.

Comment: Yeah. The difference being, it represents the differences in precedence at a type-level, and the type system in scala (afaik) cannot account for the same numeric-type constraints natively (without bringing in some Zero trait and Succ trait s.t. my terms are of the type, `Parser[Term[Zero]], Parser[Term[Succ[Zero]]`, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so there was nothing inherently impossible with what I was trying to do, it was just wrong in the details.

The core idea is just: maintain a mapping from level of precedence to operators/parsers, and recursively look for parses based on that table. If you allow parenthetical expressions, just nest a call to your most precedent possible parser within the call to the parenthetical terms' parser.

Just in case anyone else ever wants to do something like this, here's code for a set of arithmetic/logical operators, heavily commented to relate it to the above:

```
 def opExp: Parser[Exp] = {
sealed trait Assoc

val ops = Map(
  (1, Set("*", "/")),
  (2, Set("-", "+")),
  (3, Set("=", "!=", ">", "<", ">=", "<=")),
  (4, Set("&")),
  (5, Set("|"))
)

def opsWithPrecedence(n: Int): Set[String] = ops.getOrElse(n, Set.empty)

/* before, this was trying to match the remainder of the expression,
   so something like `3 - 2` would parse the Int(3),
   and try to pass "- 2" as an operator to the op parser.
   RegexParsers has an implicit def "literal : String => SubclassOfParser[String]",
   that I'm using explicitly here.
*/

def opWithPrecedence(n: Int): Parser[String] = {
  val ops = opsWithPrecedence(n)
  if (ops.size > 1) {
    ops.map(literal).fold (literal(ops.head)) {
      case (l1, l2) => l1 | l2
    }
  } else if (ops.size == 1) {
    literal(ops.head)
  } else {
    failure(s"No Ops for Precedence $n")
  }
}

def folder(h: Exp, t: TigerParser.~[String, Exp]): CallExp = CallExp(t._1, Seq(h, t._2))

val maxPrecedence: Int = ops.maxBy(_._1)._1

def term: (Int => Parser[Exp]) = {
  case 0 => lval | int | "(" ~> { term(maxPrecedence) } <~ ")"
  case n if n > 0 =>
    val lowerTerm = term(n - 1)
    lowerTerm ~ rep(opWithPrecedence(n) ~ lowerTerm) ^^ {
      case h ~ ts if ts.nonEmpty => ts.foldLeft(h)(folder)
      case h ~ _ => h
    }
}

term(maxPrecedence)
```

}